# Java Stream_Don't apply filter if my filter string is null

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have 3 filters but they are not always filled with values!

for example:

> a=1, b=2, c=null

and I have this for filtering:

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(item->item.a == a)
      .filter(item->item.b == b)
      .filter(item->item.c == c)
      .Collect(collection.asList);
```

But it does not work for me. I need the `c` parameter and its filter to be ignored if my input for `c` is `null` like this:

```
 myList.stream()
       .filter(item->item.a == a)
       .filter(item->item.b == b)
       .Collect(collection.asList);
```

And whenever each other filter is `null`, it should be removed from filter's chain like `c` in previous example.

Comment: What's the declared data type of `item.c` and of input `c`?

Comment: So change the implementation of your predicate so that it always returns true if c  is null. And please, when you ask a question, post real code. Not pseudo-code.

Comment: So `.filter(item -> item.c == null || item.c == c)`?

Comment: Thanks in advance @ernest_k. It's String

Comment: Thanks@Holger, I think its inverse of my problem, the matter is null input! not the null attribute of object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the condition to become valid, it needs the constant to be `null` or the item's value equal to the constant. This would look like:

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(item -> a == null || item.a == a)
      .filter(item -> b == null || item.b == b)
      .filter(item -> c == null || item.c == c)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

My version:

```
myList.stream()
        .filter(item -> a == null ? true : item.a.equals(a))
        .filter(item -> b == null ? true : item.b.equals(b))
        .filter(item -> c == null ? true : item.c.equals(c))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When a filter method returns true, it doesn't filter anything out. If `a`, `b` and `c` are references, as a rule you should use `equals()` for comparison, not `==`.